# Rest base URL for dialog flow API V2

Tags: dialogflow-es, appian

I have created an agent in the dialog flow and I want to use that agent in the Appian BPM. For integration, I have used google service account JSON file 
but I do not find the base URL what URL I have to keep

I want through this link https://dialogflow.com/docs but I didn't find anything in it.And I also tried https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/{session=projects/*/agent/sessions/*}:detectIntent this i didn't understand how to use.
Can some please explain clearly with a proper example

For reference please check this link:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/agNkDFgQkxomJZBb9

Answer (score 0):

As per https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api#detect_intent, it's https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/
Btw, the Google Photo link you shared doesn't work for me.